# JavaScript generate new input field on click

Tags: javascript, forms, button, dynamically-generated

I am in the process of making an HTML form where users have different options. I am trying to make a button that infinitely generates a new set op input fields with increasements in the name, like: 
The first generated input should have a name of input1. The next with a name of input2 and so on.

Here is a visual example: https://webmshare.com/ZBvw0

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can solve this problem by creating your form elements dynamically and appending them to your `form` element.

Below a simplified example, just to show the main idea.

Main points here are:

[Document.createElement()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) - Which creates a specified HTML element (your form elements in this instance).

[Node.appendChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) - Which adds a node to the end of the list of children of a specified parent node (your form element in this instance).

```js
(function() {
  var counter = 0;
  var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
  var form = document.getElementById('form');
  var addInput = function() {
    counter++;
    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.id = 'input-' + counter;
    input.type = 'text';
    input.name = 'name';
    input.placeholder = 'Input number ' + counter;
    form.appendChild(input);
  };
  btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    addInput();
  }.bind(this));
})();
```

```css
input{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<form id="form" action="">
</form>
<button id="btn" type="button">Click Me!</button>
```

Comment: I cant see what "var template" is supposed to do?

Comment: Is it still not really what I was looking for. As I said in the question, I need to create a set of inputs, not just one. An answer like the one Joshua provided would be perfect except the fact that it deletes the previous input data.

Comment: @SkinFlipNetwork in function addInput you can add any element as you wish by simply using `document.createElement()` (there you can create any type of DOM element)

Comment: As you can see here http://pastebin.com/BDUYG11p this is the block of code that needs to be duplicated each time. If I were to create an element for each item in there that would take forever. Isn't there an approach without createElement that works?

Comment: Hi. I got it working by altering the code a bit. Instead of using createElement to make an input, I had it make a div which I afterwards changed the innerHTML of so that it duplicated the exact lines of code that I need. Here's a pastebin: http://pastebin.com/ELQj8YTh

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to fetch the name of the [last](https://api.jquery.com/last/) item.

Then you can use the [javascript string replace](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) method and replace 'input' with '' in order to get the number of the last item.

Then just increment it by 1. You will have to [parse it as an integer](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp) before adding 1 to it.

Then with the incremented number, create a new input field and [append it](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/) to your container.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

HTML

```
<div id="demo">
</div>
<input type="button" id="add" value="Add input"/>
```

Javascript

```
var num = 1;
document.getElementById('add').addEventListener("click",addInput);

function addInput(){
var demo = document.getElementById('demo');
demo.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend','<div class="form-holder" style="width: 30%;"><a class="form-label">Billet type</a> <br><select name="ttype'+num+'"><option value="normal">Standard Billet</option><option value="add-on">Tilkøbs Billet</option></select></div><div class="form-holder" style="width: 31%; margin-left: 0.6%;"><a class="form-label">Billet navn</a> <br><input name="tname'+num+'" type="text" placeholder="F.eks. Entré Billet" style="width: 100%;" /></div><div class="form-holder" style="float: right; width: 18%; margin-left: 1%;"><a class="form-label">Antal</a> <br><input name="tquan'+num+'" type="text" placeholder="F.eks. 500" style="width: 100%;" /></div><div class="form-holder" style="float: right; width: 18%;"><a class="form-label">Pris (DKK)</a> <br><input name="tprice'+num+'" type="text" placeholder="F.eks. 100" style="width: 100%;" /></div> <br>');
 num++;
}
```

Check out [jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/bc4x17cg/)

Comment: There is an issue with this code. After adding a new input element all values entered before are destroyed.

Comment: Can that be fixed? Because other than that, this is exactly what I need

Comment: @SkinFlipNetwork with this code not really, to make it work you must retrieve the value of each input, store them in some place and repopulate innerHTML with HTML template included input.value. But to be honest. I see no point why you should go in this way and instead I would use a more simple approach  as using `document.createElement("input");` which is clear and does its job properly. Do you have any special requirements?

Comment: Yes. I need to create more than one input at a time. This is the exact set of inputs that I need replicated each time: http://pastebin.com/BDUYG11p

Comment: @SkinFlipNetwork i have made the necessary changes code no longer destroys values entered before

Comment: @SkinFlipNetwork i have updated my answer based on your pasteBin url to replicate the exact set of inputs you need. You can check it out here [jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/bc4x17cg/2/)